# There being no reasonable relationship

Tags: existentials, dummy-pronouns, gerund-clauses, absolute-clauses

“There being” is [allegedly](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/2811017243?r=4811050343#4811050343) an absolute phrase. Moreover, because [“there being” is the present participle of “there be”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there_being), I'd like to learn how to parse/unravel “there be”, to determine/deduce this definition *de novo.* Please explain the steps or thought process as well, so that I may do this by myself in the future.

For example, [this page on absolute phrases](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/absolutephrase.htm) says that “an absolute phrase combines a noun. . .”. What's the noun here? Are there any grammatical terms that describe this use of “there”? To what does this “there” refer?

> However, [. . .] merely submitting a derogation would not
>   have solved the shortcoming as, in any event, the provisions of the Act were disproportionate,
>   **there being** no reasonable relationship between the means employed and the
>   aims sought to be pursued by the State.
> <sub>Source: p 60, *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb is being used here in the sense of *exist*.

The simple statement would be:

> There is a simple relationship.
>   There is no simple relationship.

Now, if I want to use that statement as a subclause describing a *state*, I used the present participle:

> ..., there being a simple relationship.
>   ..., there being no simple relationship.

The thought process is not much different from:

> I am walking without an umbrella -> I don't like that it started raining, me walking down the street without an umbrella.
>   A cat is a predator -> A cat being a predator, you can't stop it from hunting.

Answer (score 0):

> An absolute phrase combines a noun and a participle with any accompanying modifiers or objects ...

This is not accurate, even in the terms employed by the author: an absolute ***clause*** may in those terms be said to combine an ***NP*** and a participle with any accompanying modifiers or objects.

But it is more helpful to think of the absolute construction as a full clause (*full* in the sense that it includes the verb, its subject and its complements) in which the heading verb is cast as a present participle.

The instance you cite is a participial version of the finite clause *there is...*; this employs the ordinary 'existential' construction in which *there* is a 'dummy subject'.